# How to validate record value with UNION type of avro schema in Java

Tags: java, avro

I am working on validating record data against `avro` schema.
Following is my schema which has union type:

```
{
   "type":"record",
   "name":"event",
   "namespace":"test",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"email",
         "type":[
            "null",
            {
               "type":"string",
               "avro.java.string":"String"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

And my record is:

```
{
   "emailAddress":"test@gmail.com"
}
```

Now I want to validate this specific field that it has a right type or not. Following is my Java code

```
// Schema
Schema dataSchema = schema.getField("data").schema();
// Converting my record into map
Map<String, Object> kafkaEvent = CustomRuleUtils.jsonStringToMap((String) kafkaEventData);
// Checking each field of schema (type and value) against this map
for (Schema.Field field : dataSchema.getFields()) {
    // if record has that field (emailAddress)
    if (kafkaEvent.get(field.name()) != null) {
        // want to check type of this record is correct or not ("test@gmail.com" is type of schema
        // HOW TO DO IT ????
        kafkaEvent.get(field.name()).getClass();
        field.schema().getTypes();
    } else {
        // invalid
    }
}
```

What will be the way to check if this value is one of the type that defined in schema.

Comment: 1) Why does it look like your event is actually JSON in code, not Avro? 2) Why do you need this? If the event types didn't match the schema, the Avro parser/deserializer would fail on its own. And not seeing how a union matters here since java strings are always nullable

Answer (score 0):

You should try some Avro serializer, for example Confluent library, to serialize the payload with your schema. It will throw exception if the library cannot serialize/validate the payload using the schema.